# Почему получаем 10 раз 10?

Tags: javascript

```js
var funcs = [];
    
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
   funcs.push(function() { return i; });
} 

for(var j = 0; j < funcs.length; j++) console.log(funcs[j]());
```

Почему анонимная функция внутри push всегда возвращает 10?

Comment: И ещё: [SetTimeout() почему при var выходит другое число](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1206117)

Answer (score 2):

Потому что функция берет значение для `i` из замыкания в **момент вызова**. А вызывается она тогда, когда `i` уже равно 10.